# How do I check a string is url encoded or not in golang?

Tags: go, url

I dont know what is the source of string it can be url encoded how do I test it whether it is a normal string or url encoded string
this using this particular code

```
func decode(str1 string) {
   //str1 := "elementINPUT61599119%5B%5D"
   resl, err := url.QueryUnescape(str1)
   log.Println(err)
   return resl
}

func ifUrlEncoded(string string) bool{
  if //function{
    return true
  }
  return false
}

func main(){
 if ifUrlEncoded(str){
   fmt.Println(decode(str))
 }
else{
 fmt.Println(str)
}
}
```

Comment: Why? In what circumstance don't you already know? If you're the server, you know that it *is* encoded, for example, and if it isn't the request isn't valid.

Comment: @user207421 I want to create a function where I will check if url encoded call this go for decoding else continue.

Comment: Can you pose the question more precisely? If you don't know the source of the string, and you don't know if it was encoded or not, then you don't know because you don't know. For example, if you see `"%20"`, maybe it's an encoded space character, or maybe it's literally supposed to be `'%', '2', '0'``

Comment: I'm with @HymnsForDisco: in a _typical_ code you always know this. For instance, in HTTP handlers the path component of the incoming request is decoded, so you just use it right away, and to obtain the query part of the URL, you call `Query()` on the request's `URL` field which deals with that. If your code is not related to handling requests, you _have to_ guess. For instance, you could look for `%` in the URL, and if one found, decode it and then validate whether you got back a valid URL; if the result is not valid, the source URL was probably not encoded. Still, it will only be a guess.

Comment: It's like asking "How do I check if some byte sequence is encoded in ISO Latin 1?". You cannot tell from the byte sequence.

Comment: sorry for my bad english I tried to reframe the question for better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find out if the string is *able* to be processed by `QueryUnescape` *before* passing it to `QueryUnescape`? If so, there's no need. If `QueryUnescape` is unable to process the string you gave, it will return an error.

```golang
decoded, err := url.QueryUnescape(originalString)

if err != nil {
    // The string was not able to be decoded this way, so treat it as a "normal" string
    decoded = originalString
}
```